# getting gap between tableview cell while assigning the image in the tableview cell

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i ve created a tableview and customized the  tableview with the image covering the entire table view cell.everything works fine but the problem is i m getting a white gap between the adjacent tableview cells.i ve even the set the tableview seperator style as null.but still not able to remove the white boder between the two adjacent cells.below is the code

[image]

code for assigning the table view image..

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
[self.tableview1 setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
[self.tableview1 setAllowsSelectionDuringEditing:TRUE];

    }

UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"listy.png"];
UIImageView *imageView1=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
imageView1.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
cell.backgroundView=imageView1;
[imageView1 release];



NSString *imagefile1 = [media1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 

NSString *escapedURL=[imagefile1 stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
mi.url=[NSURL URLWithString:escapedURL];
[objMan manage:mi];

cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
cell.textLabel.text=[story objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
cell.detailTextLabel.text=[descriptiondesc objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];


return cell;



-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath
{
return 77;
}
```

Comment: What's  the size of your cell, and what's the size of your image?

Comment: its 77..i ve updated my answer

Comment: Try putting other image, and if it is being changed. (its hard to see with a black image, try with an image with letters)

Comment: i tried to implement dis tutorial  http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/how-to-design-a-custom-uitableviewcell-from-scratch/1292/   in which i used their image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cell's background image in that tutorial is 320x84, try changing the height of your rows to 84, or resizing the image and see if that changes anything.

[image]

If you are using a "standard" cell, which it looks from your code that you are (UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle), try creating a custom cell by subclassing UITableViewCell, and add the background imageview as well as your labels in there, just like it is done in that tutorial, rather than working with a standard cell.

Comment: if i m to go for custom cell its makes my stuff more complicated ...have any clue

Comment: i was able to implement i used photoshop.der was this shadown below the cell and that was creating problem the entire time thanks for your effort

Comment: that's arguable really, if you go for custom cell, you have control on the appearance it will have, can place your labels exactly where you want them, etc ...